# Short exact sequence of vector bundles over a quasi compact scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $X$ be a quasi-compact scheme and $0 \rightarrow F_2 \rightarrow^{f} F_1 \rightarrow^{g} F_0 \rightarrow 0$  be a short exact sequence of algebraic vector bundles over $X$.

**My question is can we say that the above sequence is short exact iff it's restriction to every open affine subset $U$ of $X$ is exact.**

My area of confusion is in the surjective part of the morphism $F_1 \rightarrow^g F_0 \rightarrow 0,$ since even if $F_1 \rightarrow F_0 \rightarrow 0$ is surjective for an arbitrary scheme $Y$, there is no guarantee that $F_1(U) \rightarrow F_0(U)$ is surjective. But in case of quasi compact schemes is it possible to bypass this constraint?

The way I am trying to solve it is from the perspective of stalks. Since $X = \bigcup_{i=1}^n Spec(A_i)$ for every $x \in X; x \in Spec(A_i)$ for some $i$ then at stalk level I have a short exact sequence of the form $0 \rightarrow {A_{i}}_{p}^n \rightarrow {A_{i}}_{p}^m \rightarrow {A_i}_{p}^l \rightarrow 0.$ So from here is it possible for me to conclude?

Any hints or suggestions would be really helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quasicompactness of $X$ is irrelevant, and the statement is true more generally for a sequence of quasicoherent sheaves. Note also that if $\mathrm{Spec} A$ is an arbitrary open affine subset of $X$, even if $F$ is a locally free sheaf on $X$, it might not be true that $F|_{\mathrm{Spec} A}$ is the sheaf associated to a free $A$-module $A^{\oplus n}$; you might need to shrink $\mathrm{Spec} A$ to a smaller affine open to get this. Therefore, for your question, you really do need to consider a broader class of modules if you want to get the statement for *every* open affine subset.

On any affine open subset $U = \mathrm{Spec} A$, each sheaf $F_i|_U$ is the sheaf associated to the $A$-module $M_i := F_i(U)$, and the sequence of maps $F_2|_U \to F_1|_U \to F_0|_U$ is induced by the sequence of maps $M_2 \to M_1 \to M_0$. This is the fact that, on $\mathrm{Spec} A$, the category of quasicoherent sheaves is equivalent to the category of $A$-modules via the sheaf-associated-to-a-module construction.

One can check that exactness of a sequence of $A$-modules is a local property: the sequence $0 \to M_{2, \mathfrak{p}} \to M_{1, \mathfrak{p}} \to M_{0, \mathfrak{p}} \to 0$ is exact for all prime ideals $\mathfrak{p} \subset A$ if and only if $0 \to M_2 \to M_1 \to M_0 \to 0$ is exact. Since exactness of a sequence of sheaves can also be checked stalk-locally––and the maps on stalks are those  same maps $M_{2, \mathfrak{p}} \to M_{1, \mathfrak{p}} \to M_{0, \mathfrak{p}}$––you can conclude that the sequence of sheaves is short exact if and only if the sequence of sections on each affine is short exact. Taking an arbitrary affine cover works for the reverse direction: nothing about finiteness of the cover is needed here.

Comment: Thank you got it.